# How long does it take for Ireland to process a work permit and entry permit?

Tags: ireland, work-permit, entry-permit

My friend who is in Sri Lanka is required to travel to Ireland in October to start work there. But her work permit is getting delayed because of some delays on their side. 
Normally, how long does it take to process the work permit, and how long does it take to get the entry permit afterwards?

Comment: This question should be asked in the sister site: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the type of application, it can take months for processing. Right now, the Department of Business, Enterprise and Innovation is showing [Current Processing Dates for Employment Permits](https://dbei.gov.ie/en/What-We-Do/Workplace-and-Skills/Employment-Permits/Current-Application-Processing-Dates/):

> As of the 16 July we are processing applications received on the following dates for the specific types of applications:
>
> Trusted Partner: 5 June 2018
>   Standard: 9 April 2018

As for entry permit, in general it can take up to 60 days for a long stay visa to be issued.